# how to add multiple item in Inventory model in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am developing an inventory app in django which have Purchase, Stock and sell model. How can I purchase multiple item under one purchase invoice. I have done this with PHP session now want to convert app to python django.

This is for tracking purchase, sell history. I have tried many to many example by django Group Member example but unable to update stock when sell and purchase.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

class Purchase(models.Model):
    invoice = models.CharField(null=False)
    invoice_date = models.DateField()
    seller = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    item = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
    perform_by = models.ForeignKey(User)  # Authenticated user

class Stock(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

class Sale(models.Model):
    invoice = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    invoice_date = models.DateField()
    item = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

I expected stock value

### Item    type     quantity

### A           Red       20

### A    Green   15

### B    Red 10

and also update stock value when sell and purchase an item.
But could not find the stock value. What thing I need to update. Thank in advance

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking here. Nothing in the code you've given shows how a user actually interacts with the site

Comment: Please add views.py and urls.py.

Comment: When I will purchase an item it will invoke stock value of that item and when sell item decrease stock value of that item